# Wordpress настройка добавления записи

Tags: wordpress

Начал изучат WP, подскажите в каком направлении двигаться что - бы сделать следующее:
Имеется блок

```
<div class="services_plate">
    <h3 class="services_plate_header">Налоговая и бухгалтерская отчетность</h3>
    <div class="services_content">
       <ul class="services_content_list">
          <li class="services_content_list_element">что - то</li>
          <li class="services_content_list_element">что - то</li>
          <li class="services_content_list_element">что - то</li>
          <li class="services_content_list_element">что - то</li>
          <li class="services_content_list_element">что - то</li>
      </ul>
      <a href="" class="services_content_link">Заказат услугу</a>
</div>
```

если делать так:

```
<div class="services_plate_box">
   <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
   <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   <div class="services_plate">
     <h3 class="services_plate_header"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
     <?php the_content(); ?>
     <div class="services_content">
        <ul class="services_content_list">
          <li class="services_content_list_element">какой-то текст</li>
        </ul>
       <a href="" class="services_content_link">Заказат услугу</a>
    </div>
 </div>           
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

то запись добавляется, но вот как сделать возможность добавлять текст в список, соответственно пунктов списка может быть произвольное количество.

Comment: можно использовать custom fields как плагином так и штатно и соответствующей функцией выводить. статья в кодексе https://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields

Comment: можно через the_content() если хранить текст услуги в теле поста

Comment: @kandellak, _можно через the_content()_ можно подробней как это осуществить?

Comment: ну если организовать хранение информации о услугах в записях, в самом теле записи пусть будет описание, если нужны доп. поля то и их прикрутить и в цикле вывести, вот здесь пример https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB_WordPress

Comment: @kandellak, буду разбираться.... Думал все просто, да не тут то было....